# Gui button wont click javaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx

My project is a calculator. I have given the 0 button function enrolling 0 to TextField but it does not work. Some smart people out there that have a solution?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("This is a caculator");

    TextArea result = new TextArea("This is where the result will be"); result.setPrefSize(480,50); result.setLayoutX(10); result.setLayoutY(65);
    TextField textField = new TextField();  textField.setPrefSize(480,50); textField.setLayoutX(10);    textField.setLayoutY(10);

    Button button1 = new Button("1");       button1.setPrefSize(100,50);        button1.setTranslateX(30);      button1.setTranslateY(140);
    Button button2 = new Button("2");       button2.setPrefSize(100,50);        button2.setTranslateX(150);     button2.setTranslateY(140);
    Button button3 = new Button("3");       button3.setPrefSize(100,50);        button3.setTranslateX(270);     button3.setTranslateY(140);
    Button button4 = new Button("4");       button4.setPrefSize(100,50);        button4.setTranslateX(30);      button4.setTranslateY(210);
    Button button5 = new Button("5");       button5.setPrefSize(100,50);        button5.setTranslateX(150);     button5.setTranslateY(210);
    Button button6 = new Button("6");       button6.setPrefSize(100,50);        button6.setTranslateX(270);     button6.setTranslateY(210);
    Button button7 = new Button("7");       button7.setPrefSize(100,50);        button7.setTranslateX(30);      button7.setTranslateY(280);
    Button button8 = new Button("8");       button8.setPrefSize(100,50);        button8.setTranslateX(150);     button8.setTranslateY(280);
    Button button9 = new Button("9");       button9.setPrefSize(100,50);        button9.setTranslateX(270);     button9.setTranslateY(280);
    Button button0 = new Button("0");       button0.setPrefSize(100,50);        button0.setTranslateX(150);     button0.setTranslateY(350);
    Button buttonPlus = new Button("+");    buttonPlus.setPrefSize(100,50);     buttonPlus.setTranslateX(390);  buttonPlus.setTranslateY(210);
    Button buttonMinus = new Button("-");   buttonMinus.setPrefSize(100,50);    buttonMinus.setTranslateX(390); buttonMinus.setTranslateY(280);
    Button buttonMulti = new Button("*");   buttonMulti.setPrefSize(100,50);    buttonMulti.setTranslateX(390); buttonMulti.setTranslateY(350);
    Button buttonDivide = new Button("/");  buttonDivide.setPrefSize(100,50);   buttonDivide.setTranslateX(270);buttonDivide.setTranslateY(350);
    Button buttonClear = new Button("C");   buttonClear.setPrefSize(100,50);    buttonClear.setTranslateX(390); buttonClear.setTranslateY(140);
    Button buttonResult = new Button("=");  buttonResult.setPrefSize(100,50);   buttonResult.setTranslateX(30); buttonResult.setTranslateY(350);
    Button virus = new Button("Install the deadly virus"); virus.setPrefSize(450,50);   virus.setTranslateX(30);virus.setTranslateY(430);

    Pane pane = new Pane(textField,result,button1,button2,button3,buttonClear,button4,button5,button6,buttonPlus,button7,button8,button9,buttonMinus,buttonMulti,buttonDivide,button0,buttonResult,virus);

    button0.setOnAction(event -> textField.setText("0"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500,500);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/css/Style.css");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to expand on "but it doesn't work"... From what I can see it does exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: It works as expected for me. Pressing `button0` sets the text of `textField` to "0". Are you meaning that it isn't continuously adding 0's? You would have to do for example `textField.setText(textField.getText() + "0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will assume you want to append it, concatenate, add it to the end (All the same meaning whatever)

```
button0.setOnAction(e -> button0.appendText("0");
// // // OR // // //
button0.setOnAction(e -> button0.setText(button0.getText() + "0");
```

Both will give the same result, but I like the first one better, being more elegant.